# Characterizing the set of first-order definable real functions

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic, nonstandard-analysis

I am trying to characterize the set of first-order definable functions $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ and see what properties they have.

It is immediately clear that these functions are not all analytic everywhere, since you have things like the absolute value function, the nearest integer function, the "give me the 10'th bit of the binary expansion of this real number" function, and so on. All of these above functions are instead piecewise-analytic functions.

Being piecewise-analytic is a fairly broad notion, but it still isn't everything: there are some important first-order definable functions such as the Weierstrass function, which are not piecewise-analytic. This is instead an infinite series of cosine functions, which are all analytic.

Similarly, the Cantor function is first-order definable, and expressed fairly easily as the limit of a sequence of piecewise-analytic functions (in particular piecewise-constant functions).

Both of these series/sequences are themselves first-order definable and converge pointwise. So far, every first-order definable function I have seen is of this form.

Is *every* first-order definable function of this form, i.e. the limit of some first-order definable sequence of analytic (or piecewise-analytic) functions that converges pointwise to it?

(To keep it simple I wrote the above in terms of total functions $\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ but also interested in partial functions, e.g. $f(x) = 1/x$.)

Comment: "First-order definable" *where*? What's the ambient structure (e.g. $(\mathbb{R};+,\times)$, or $V$, or ...)? The answer will depend highly on this. For example, $(\mathbb{R};+,\times)$ is o-minimal so $\sin(x)$ isn't definable over it even allowing parameters.

Comment: @NoahSchweber maybe I have the wrong terminology, but in nonstandard analysis I thought the transfer principle gives a hyperreal extension $^*f$ to any "first-order definable" function $f$. Does that mean first-order definable in $V$?

Comment: Nope, you get transfer for **all** functions. (You typically construct a hyperreal field as a nontrivial ultrapower of $\mathbb{R}$ equipped with all functions and relations.)

Comment: OK, I think I was mixing two things up. The hyperreals satisfy the same first-order properties that the reals do. This means any first-order statement that is true of the real numbers is true of the hyperreal numbers. I interpreted that as first-order predicates have an "extension" to the hyperreal numbers; e.g. the predicate $P(x) = \text{"x is an even integer"}$ (which can be formalized a few different ways) has an extension to the hyperintegers. Before I even get to functions, is that right so far?

Comment: I think I see the issue. It doesn't really make sense to say "the hyperreals satisfy the same first-order properties that the reals do" (even after we fix a specific set to be our hyperreals); we need to turn each set into a **structure**. If $\mathfrak{R}$ is any structure with underlying set $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathcal{U}$ is a nonprincipal ultrapower on $\omega$, then $\mathfrak{R}$ will satisfy the same first-order sentences as its ultrapower $\prod\mathfrak{R}/\mathcal{U}$. We generally take $\mathfrak{R}$ to be $\mathbb{R}$ equipped with all functions/relations.

Comment: OK. If I understand correctly, the set of "all functions" from $\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ has all of the first-order definable ones, as well as a bunch of undefinable ones. Then I guess I meant those functions from $\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ which are definable in first-order ZFC.